# Apache VirtualHost ignored

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have two vhost files in my `sites-enabled`:

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName www.example.com
    #ServerAlias *

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

mysite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, my problem is that when I try to access mysite.com, it returns the default site (from 000-default.conf), but for www.mysite.com it's working as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when the systems underlying hostname is "mysite.com" because it implicitly becomes the ServerName of your first-listed virtual host.

Set a dummy ServerName in the default/first-listed virtualhost and never leave it blank.

Comment: I tried `ServerName www.example.com` but nothing changed

Comment: Share apachectl -S  output?

Comment: Actually it's working now, I uncommented only ServerName but not ServerAlias in the default host.